# Problem with square root of (2147483647) in c++

Tags: c++

I am calculating square root of 2147483647 by sqrt function.and the result must be a float value 46340.95 but my code returns the value 46341.
  Can anyone tell me where is the problem? 
i am using code :

```
double x=2147483647.0;
double y=sqrt(x);
cout<< y;
```

Comment: What type of variable is your answer going into?

Comment: We can't help you if you don't show your code.

Comment: No: we can't see what your code looks like.

Comment: -1: Red herring question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get that same result. But, if I inject a `setprecision`, I get the right value:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

int main (void) {
    double x=2147483647.0;
    double y=sqrt(x);
    std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << y << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

gives me:

```
46340.95
```

In fact, if you use the folowing code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

int main (void) {
    double x=2147483647.0;
    double y=sqrt(x);
    std::cout << y << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(0) << std::fixed << y << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(1) << std::fixed << y << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed << y << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(3) << std::fixed << y << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

you get:

```
46341
46341
46341.0
46340.95
46340.950
```

So it appears that the default setting (at least for my environment) is a precision of zero.

If you *want* a specific format, I suggest you explicitly request it.

Answer (score 1):

This trivial code yields 46340.9:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    float x = std::sqrt(2147483647);
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What does your code look like?

(Just for the record: tested using GCC (g++) 4.5.2 on MacOS X 10.6.6.)

Answer (score 1):

The default precision for `cout` is not sufficient to show the fractional part of your result. Your result is 46340.95, which rounded to six digits of precision is 43641.0, and is displayed as 43641 by `cout`. To show more precision, set the precision of `cout` first:

```
double x=2147483647.0;
double y=sqrt(x);
cout.precision(9);
cout<< y;
```

On my system this shows a result of 46340.95.